# Torch 7 - parameters questions

Tags: lua, torch, conv-neural-network

I am confused when I see this line in torch 7 demos;

```
if x ~= parameters then
     parameters:copy(x)
end
```

for example in this documentation at line 147;

https://github.com/torch/tutorials/blob/master/2_supervised/4_train.lua

Does anyone know what this is trying to do in the context of the training process? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The x is the parameter of feval(x), and feval is called in optimMethod (e.g. optim.sgd). This means that optimMethod will call the feval function with updated parameters (x). This if statement you mention, will update the parameters of the model with the parameters sent from optimMethod. The statement parameters:copy(x) means copy from x.

Answer (score -1):

if table *parameters* has not the same address as table *x*, then do parameters:copy(x)

Comment: Sorry I am still not quite sure. x is not defined anywhere? And what is the exact motive behind it?

Comment: @mattdns, x is an argument of the function feval. Motive is to use a passed argument as a parameters and keep it for later use